# How do you fadeIn and animate at the same time?

Tags: jquery, effects, jquery-animate, fadein

Using jQuery I'm creating a basic 'tooltip' animation so that the tooltip will appear in a little animation in which it fades into view as well as move vertically.

So far I have this:

```
$('.tooltip').fadeIn('slow');
$('.tooltip').animate({ top: "-10px" }, 'slow');
```

Doing it that way or this way:

```
$('.tooltip').fadeIn('slow').animate({ top: "-10px" }, 'slow');
```

The animations will run one at a time, the fade in first and then the vertical animation. Is there a way to have it do both at the same time?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
$('.tooltip').animate({ opacity: 1, top: "-10px" }, 'slow');
```

However, this doesn't appear to work on `display: none` elements (as `fadeIn` does). So, you might need to put this beforehand:

```
$('.tooltip').css('display', 'block');
$('.tooltip').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
```

Comment: +1. However, `$('.tooltip').show()` is a better alternative to `$('.tooltip').css('display', 'block');`.

Comment: What about IEs `{filter:alpha(opacity=50);}`? Does this take care of this option too?

Answer (score 51):

For people still looking a couple of years later, things have changed a bit. You can now use the `queue` for `.fadeIn()` as well so that it will work like this:

```
$('.tooltip').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'slow'});
$('.tooltip').animate({ top: "-10px" }, 'slow');
```

This has the benefit of working on `display: none` elements so you don't need the extra two lines of code.

Comment: queue is powerful option, specially when working on animation effects, Thanks so much.

Answer (score 16):

Another way to do simultaneous animations if you want to call them separately (eg. from different code) is to use `queue`. Again, as with Tinister's answer you would have to use animate for this and not fadeIn:

```
$('.tooltip').css('opacity', 0);
$('.tooltip').show();
...

$('.tooltip').animate({opacity: 1}, {queue: false, duration: 'slow'});
$('.tooltip').animate({ top: "-10px" }, 'slow');
```