# Run two actions at the same time, fadein() & animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you fadeIn and animate at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652576/how-do-you-fadein-and-animate-at-the-same-time)

I would like to fade in and animate a div in a same time by using jquery.
Here is my code:

```
$('#div').fadeIn('slow').animate({'left' : '5%'}, duration);
```

The problem is, I'm fading first and then, the div is starting to animated itself;

I tried this too, but I had no result:

```
$('#div').fadeIn('slow');
$('#div').animate({'left' : '5%'}, duration);
```

Thanks

Comment: you can tryout the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/dXCPF/1/

```
$('#div').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':'0'})
         .animate({'opacity':'1','left':'5%'}, 1500);
```

first i did the `display:none;` then applied the css with jQuery and animated it too. Seems both effects at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use `animate()` for both:

```
$('#div').animate({
    'left' : '5%',
    'opacity' : 1
}, 600);
```

Comment: Best solution in here IMO

Answer (score 1):

animate doesn't appear to work on `display: none` elements (as `fadeIn` does). So, you might need to put this before using `animate`:

```
$('#div').css('display', 'block');
//then use animate
$('#div').animate({'left' : '5%'}, duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#div').animate({ 
    opacity: 1
}, { duration: slow, queue: false });
$('#div').animate({
   left: '5%'
}, { duration: duration, queue: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use

```
$('#div').fadeIn(fast).animate({'left' : '5%'}, fast);
```