# jQuery Slide CSS Element Out Reducing Opacity

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I am trying to slide a CSS element out, gradually removing the opacity until it is fully disappeared.

e.g I want to slide a text to the right which reduced opacity whilst it is sliding till its fully disappeared.

```
//JQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.heading1').animate({marginRight:"20px",opacity:0},500)
})
//HTML
<div class="sliderContainer">

<a class="heading1">Text</a>

</div>

//CSS
.heading1 {
    position:relative;  
}
```

I have tried this but it doesn't really slide out, like move across the screen. It just fades out. Any idea?

I want to be able to animate it in and out of the screen reducing opacity when it does.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LXsBm/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652576/how-do-you-fadein-and-animate-at-the-same-time

it´s solved here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integers (`20`) instead of strings (`20px`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.heading1').animate({'margin-right':20,opacity:0},500);
})
```

Comment: That did not work, also, why do u have "''" around margin-right and not opacity. It just fades out due to opacity, but doesent slide out whilst its doing that.

Comment: `'margin-right'` is separated with a *delimeter* `-` and can not be used as an `object key`. However, this code works fine for me. You may have to look at your css settings ?

Comment: Do you have to do anything with the CSS element? I tried setting .heading1 position: relative. but didint work either. Check my edited OP. Edit i understand why it didint work because it didint have any more margin remove to move to the right