# animate and fade in at the same time - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've puzzled over this for ages, but I can't seem to pinpoint how to make an .animate and a .fadeIn happen simultaneously, rather than consecutively.

So when I try it, the object fades in, and then moves, but I would LOVE to achieve something like this:

http://www.schoolwebsite.com/ - see the tooltips that appear on hovering social media icons at the bottom of the page for instance

See my bodged attempt below

```
$(".content_slider li a").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.hover_arrow').animate({
        "bottom": "+=100px"
    }, "fast").fadeIn('fast');
},function () {
    $(this).find('div.hover_arrow').animate({
        "bottom": "+=100px"
    }, "fast").fadeOut('fast');
})
```

Any assistance is massively appreciated :)

Comment: check this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652576/how-do-you-fadein-and-animate-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `fadein` as a separate method, why don't you use opacity with the animate method?

```
$(this).find('.hover_arrow').animate({"bottom": "+=100px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast")}
```

You'd have to change your CSS to have the item as "`opacity: 0`" instead of just `display: none;`, but you'd be able to include the effect in a single function

If you want to retain display: none (for a clean interface), you might want to include this call as well:

```
$(this).find('.hover_arrow').show() //display: block
$(this).find('.hover_arrow').animate({"bottom": "+=100px", "opacity": "1"}, "fast")} //opacity: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `animate` and `fadeIn` have the `queue` option.

By default they end up in the same queue, and are therefore performed after another.

Either put them in separate queues, or don't queue them at all.

See also:
[What are queues in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me)