# How to run a fadein effect halfway while a div is animating?(moving up)

Tags: jquery, animation

I want a `div` to `fadeIn` while it's animating(moving up), and the `fadeIn` needs to occur during the final 2 seconds of the animation just as it is completes.

Please note that I don't want it to both `fadeIn` and `animate` simultaneously, the `fadeIn` needs to occur halfway through the animation as the `div` is moving up.

```
    $('header').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000)

$('header').animate({ 
    'marginTop': '-=200px'
}, 2000);
```

The animations are just queued one after the other and I can't get them to work halfway through.

Comment: write your code that You have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine when the animation is at its half, you can use the step-option of the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)-function.

> A function to be called for each animated property of each animated
>   element. This function provides an opportunity to modify the Tween
>   object to change the value of the property before it is set.

In order to start the second animation (the `fadeIn`) directly, you have to specify the `queue`-option of the animation to `false` or [dequeue](https://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) the different animation manually.

```
var marginTop = 200;
var flag = false;
$('header').animate({
    'marginTop': '-=' + marginTop  + 'px'
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 2000,
    step: function(now){
        if(now <= marginTop/2 && !flag){
            $(this).fadeIn();
            flag = true;
        }
    }
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2txtxyu8/3/)**

Read more about the jQUery animation-queue [here](https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, though I had to do a cartload of tweaking with pixel values and time durations before I got the right effect.

Comment: Has my upvote but I have to comment that the `fadeIn()` fires 100+ times. A switch might be a good idea.

Comment: @Shikkediel thanks, yes you're right, I didn't thought about that, added a variable to cope with that.

Comment: I don't understand... how could `fadeIn()` fire 100+ times?

Comment: Always looking for a tweak - and a little glad I could spot something in return. :-D

Comment: @Shikkediel @empiric Can someone show me the light here? How does `fadeIn()` fire 100+ times?

Comment: The step function fires on *every* step of the animation (many times a second) so the `fadeIn()` would be triggered as well (during the second half at least). But adding a variable that serves as a switch to make it only trigger once should be enough. It's definitely the niftiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would run an animate function twice, something like this:

```
$('#header').animate({
    'marginTop': '-=100px'
}, 1000, function(){ 
    $('#header').animate({
        'marginTop': '-=100px',
        'opacity': 1
    }, 1000)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o0w4vhb3/

Comment: There's a break between the two animate()s, you can clearly see it if you keep it visible the whole time by adding opacity: 1 in the css. So in the end, it's just the second animate() running along simultaneously with fadeIn() while the first animate() runs hidden. Not the effect I was looking for, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I would be to do it in two steps, mimicking what `.fadeIn()` does :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wavmBw?editors=011

```
header {
opacity: 0;
}
```

```
$('header')
.animate({marginTop: '-=100'}, 1000, 'linear')
.animate({marginTop: '-=100', opacity: 1}, 1000, 'linear');
```

Edit - @empiric had a good point in the comments so I've changed the approach a bit to the most direct option. This would have the same result as a `fadeIn()` (but doesn't seem very necessary) :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wavmBw?editors=011

```
var header = $('header');

header.css({display: 'none', opacity: 0});

// other stuff may be going on first

header
.css('display', 'block')
.animate({marginTop: '-=100'}, 1000, 'linear')
.animate({marginTop: '-=100', opacity: 1}, 1000, 'linear');
```

Edit - as mentioned in the comments, the animations would need to be `linear` to appear smooth.

Comment: Note: this will assume the `header` is hidden through `opacity: 0`. Depending on how the `header` is hidden, you have to set display before the second animation.

Comment: Good point, I'll add a live example to clear some of that up.

Comment: @Shikkediel - actually its not true. `fadeIn()` is not sync. and you can chain those animation and run them simultaneously.

Comment: Really, you gonna downvote over a detail while I'm still editing?

Comment: Can you temme why you're changing the `display` property from `none` to `block`, and also are `display: 'none'` and `opacity: 0` the same?

Comment: @Jeevan Elements with `display:none` will not reserve any space in the document, whereas `opacity:0` will only make the element invisible but the space is used.

Comment: Better answer than I posted. ;-)

Comment: There's a break between the two `animate()`s, you can clearly see it if you keep it visible the whole time by adding `opacity: 1` in the css. So in the end, it's just the second `animate()` running along simultaneously with `fadeIn()` while the first `animate()` runs hidden. Not the effect I was looking for, sorry :(

Comment: Yeah I know what causing that... well noticed. It's the default 'swing' animation. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

You can run both animation simultaneously by disabling queuing of the first one like this:

```js
$('.header').css('opacity', 0);
$('.header').show();

$('.header').animate({ 'marginTop': '-=200px' }, {queue: false, duration: 2000});
$('.header').animate({opacity: 1}, 3000 );
```

```css
.header {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">test</div>
```

Adjust the durations as needed.

Reference: [How do you fadeIn and animate at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652576/how-do-you-fadein-and-animate-at-the-same-time)

Comment: There's a break between the two animate()s, you can clearly see it if you keep it visible the whole time by adding opacity: 1 in the css. So in the end, it's just the second animate() running along simultaneously with fadeIn() while the first animate() runs hidden. Not the effect I was looking for, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Found!!!

**PURE jQuery - fadeIn() + animate()**

If you want to use a `display:none` element and still get the two effects then 
Simply hide it using `jQuery` or inline style.

Problems to solve:

- `.animate()` can't animate the display property - so we use `fadeIn`.
- `.animate()` is added to an animation queue- so we set `queue: false`.

```js
$('div').hide();
$('div').fadeIn(3000).animate({ 'marginTop': '-=200px' }, { queue: false, duration: 2000 });
```

```css
div { margin-top:200px; background-color:blue; height:50px; width:500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

**BONUS - only CSS**:

Use `opacity` and delay the animation:

CSS: [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/mtdgc2dg/)

```
#ifade  { 
   margin-top:50px; 
   opacity:0;
   -moz-transition : margin-top 2s linear 0s, opacity 1s linear .6s;   
    -webkit-transition : margin-top 2s linear 0s, opacity 1s linear .6s;   
     transition : margin-top 2s linear 0s, opacity 1s linear .6s;   
}
```

Have Fun!

Comment: No CSS tag in the question. Plus OP wants to fade in *halfway*.

Comment: The css is just a bonus the first method uses pure jQuery

Comment: @Shikkediel  - Are you serious? only CSS is extra + OP can set the duration's to whatever he wants - btw its already halfway.

Comment: Sure, the bonus is fine but it fades in right from the start.

Comment: I'm not the one asking the question. The OP has described the desired effect.