# Fade to Slide Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I got this website, www.harispapadakis.eu and I'm using this code

```
function changeBackground() {
    ++currentBackground > 2 && (currentBackground = 0),
    $(".c-hero").fadeOut(4e3, function() {
        $(".c-hero").css({
            "background-image": "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        }), 
        $(".c-hero").fadeIn(3e3)
    }), 
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 15e3)
}

var currentBackground = 0,
    backgrounds = [];

backgrounds[0] = "media/main.jpg", 
backgrounds[1] = "media/main2.jpg", 
backgrounds[2] = "media/main3.jpg", 
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 7500)
});
```

(edit note: formatted from minified code, in which `if` is minified to `&&`, `;` is minified to `,` and `3000` is minified to `3e3`)

This code, is changing with FadeIn and FadeOut the background src...

I want to change the fade with slide to left... It's changing the background picture and I want a nice animation..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**! You have to show that you've put some efford into solving your own problem. Seems to me you simply took some code and you're asking us to change it's behaviour to what you want for you. Evidence being minified code formatted by Derek for you.

Comment: I found that code on web and I change it a bit. I putted the fade. I don't know if exist something like that I'm asking for, that's why I posted like that.

Comment: Does it exist? Yes. It's called an Image Slider. You would have to program it yourself or download one of the many available libraries for it out there. For example: https://www.jssor.com/ or https://amazingslider.com/ You will still need to change its behaviour to automaticly slide images for you and set them on the background.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help: [How do you fadeIn and animate at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652576/how-do-you-fadein-and-animate-at-the-same-time)

Rather than using .fadeIn, consider using jQuery's .animate function to perform multiple css transitions.

For example, instead of:

```
$(".c-hero").fadeIn(3e3)
```

Try doing @see http://api.jquery.com/animate/:

```
$(".c-hero").animate(
   {opacity: 1, left: "-=50"}, // css attributes to animate
   3000, // duration in seconds
   function(){ /**callback function after it completes**/}
 });
```

Comment: Read the question again. `It's changing the background picture`. You can't use animate to change pictures. He's looking for an Image Slider.